# Delete css rule inserted with .insertRule by key and not index

Tags: javascript, css

Say I insert a rule like this:

```
var style = document.createElement("style")
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""))
head.appendChild(style)

// done multiple times throughout the code
var index = style.sheet.insertRule(".myClass { color: red; }", style.sheet.cssRules.length)
var myRule = style.sheet.cssRules[index]
```

The `style.sheet.deleteRule` function expects an index, and when I delete a rule, all the indexes will change. Therefore, just storing the rules' index, wont suffice.

How can I delete a certain `myRule` at any given time without looping through all the rules of the `style.sheet.cssRules`?

Comment: Why are you inserting and deleting rules?

Comment: Because I want to dynamically insert tags, which in turn should have a dynamic style. So after i remove the tag from the DOM, I would like to remove its style too.

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46941964/104380

Answer (score 1):

First the index of a rule needs to be searched for, so here is a function I've created, named `getStyleRuleIndexBySelector` which can look at a certain stylesheet and return the indexes of the matching rules.

```js
// create a dummy stylesheet which we'll search a key by value
var style = document.createElement("style")
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""))
document.head.appendChild(style);

// insert some rules
style.sheet.insertRule('.first{ color:red }', style.sheet.cssRules.length);
style.sheet.insertRule('.second{ color:green }', style.sheet.cssRules.length);
style.sheet.insertRule('div span a{ color:blue }', style.sheet.cssRules.length);
style.sheet.insertRule('.second{ display:none; left:1px; }', style.sheet.cssRules.length);

// get the rules
var rules = style.sheet.cssRules;

// print rules
console.log("Stylesheet rules: ", Array.from(rules).map(item => item.cssText ) );

function getStyleRuleIndexBySelector(rules, selector, prop){
  var result = [], i,
      value = (prop ? selector + "{" + prop + "}" : selector).replace(/\s/g, ''), // remove whitespaces
      s = prop ? "cssText" : "selectorText";
  
  for( i=0; i < rules.length; i++ )
    if( rules[i][s].replace(/\s/g, '') == value)
      result.push(i);
      
  return result;
}

console.log( "Rules's indexes with selector '.second':", getStyleRuleIndexBySelector(rules, '.second' )  );
console.log( "Rule index by specific selector & props:", getStyleRuleIndexBySelector(rules, '.second', 'display:none; left:1px;')  );

// delete a certain rule (by specificly stating the Selector & its properties
style.sheet.deleteRule( getStyleRuleIndexBySelector(rules, '.second', 'display:none; left:1px;')[0] );

// print the rules
console.log("Stylesheet rules after removal: ", Array.from(rules).map(item => item.cssText ) );
```

---

This is related to another answer of mine for this question:
[Get index of a CSS rule by name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50781988/104380)

Another related answer of mine: [Changing pseudo-element style from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50782696/104380)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `ruleIndexTracker` **Array** which will serve as a key, translating the original index of the inserted rule to that rule's current index.

eg.

```
var ruleIndexTracker = [

    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
];
```

Every time you add a new rule to the `style.sheet`, add a `value` to `ruleIndexTracker`.

```
var nextIndex = (ruleIndexTracker[(ruleIndexTracker.length - 1)] + 1);
ruleIndexTracker.push(nextIndex);
```

So if you add a sixth and a seventh rule, you will get:

```
var ruleIndexTracker = [

    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6
];
```

You can see that you will always have an array with exactly the same number of entries as rules you have added to `style.sheet` (regardless of whether those rules are still present or whether they have been subsequently deleted).

If you want to remove a rule, run the following function:

```
function deleteRule(originalIndex) {

    ruleIndexTracker[originalIndex] = -1;

    for (let i = (originalIndex + 1); i < ruleIndexTracker.length; i++) {

        ruleIndexTracker[i] = (ruleIndexTracker[i] - 1);
    }
}
```

If you now wish to remove the fourth rule you added (which *always* corresponds to `ruleIndexTracker[3]` then running the function `deleteRule(3)` above will result in the following:

```
var ruleIndexTracker = [

    0,
    1,
    2,
   -1,
    3,
    4,
    5
];
```

Every time you need to delete a rule from the `style.sheet`, you will always be able to find that rule using the following:

```
ruleIndexTracker[originalIndex]
```

This will always reveal the current index of that rule in `style.sheet`.

Answer (score 0):

Is going to be easier if you save the rule object.

```
var style = document.createElement("style")
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""))
head.appendChild(style)

// done multiple times throughout the code
var index = style.sheet.insertRule(".myClass { color: red; }"
var myRule = style.sheet.cssRules[index]

//LATER
removeRule(myRule) 

function removeRule(rule){
 let sheet = rule.parentStylesheet
 let index = Object.values(sheet.cssRules).indexOf(rule)
 sheet.deleteRule(index)
}
```