# Update or remove css rule from insertRule() in JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have inserted a rule (with a for) with the following :

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(`#li${i}:after {content: "${data[2][i]}"; }`, 0);
```

How can I update or remove it ?

Why ? :
Because if I run my for loop a second time with new data it won't update the content of the hover
(I need it in here : https://vengeur69.github.io/public/Wikipedia_api/)

Example :

[I get data with the term "yes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yUnH.png)

[I get data with the term "no" but the content didn't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjQsu.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To delete just use [deleteRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule) passing in the index that the rule was inserted at

```
var index = document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(`#li${i}:after {content: "${data[2][i]}"; }`, 0);
document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(index);
```

In order to update a rule access the `cssRules` list at the index the rule was inserted at, and change the style property

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[index].style.content = "";
```

Note you will not be able to access the rule if the style sheet being accessed was linked externally as `cssRules` will be null. So you will have to delete it and insert it back to change its styles.

Demo

```js
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var ruleIndex = 0;

function redRule(){
  stylesheet.cssRules[ruleIndex].style.color = "red";
}

function blueRule(){
  stylesheet.cssRules[ruleIndex].style.color = "blue";
}

function replaceRule(){
  stylesheet.deleteRule(ruleIndex);
  ruleIndex = stylesheet.insertRule("body { color:yellow; }",0);    
}

ruleIndex = stylesheet.insertRule("body { color:black; }",0);

document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
 switch(e.target.id){
   case 'red':
     redRule();
     break;
   case 'blue':
     blueRule();
     break;
   case 'replace':
     replaceRule();
     break;
 }
});
```

```html
<style></style>
Text<br>
<button id="red">Change rule to red</button><br>
<button id="blue">Change rule to blue</button><br>
<button id="replace">Replace rule</button><br>
```

Comment: Ok thank you! I added the rules in a array and i managed to delete every rules before my for loop